# Need help in excel to perform 4 cell lookup and copy in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have found VLOOKUP and it does not seem to match all of the criteria I need to perform.
The following is what has stopped me at this time. I would appreciate any assistance.

in excel, I need to match a value from a specific cell in spreadsheet A, column B, with a range of values in spreadsheet B, column C. Then in the row that the value  in spreadsheet B is found, I need to obtain the value for the cell in column P and copy it into spreadsheet A column N.

Thank you,

Comment: [Index/Match](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions03.html). In your case, in column N type: `=Index(SheetB!P:P,Match(SheetA!B1,SheetB!C:C,0))`, adjust for any references as necessary.

Comment: Why does VLOOKUP not work for you? something like in A!N2 put =VLOOKUP(A!B2,B!$C$2:$P$1000,14,false)

Comment: good point @CharlesWilliams. I didn't even see that it is all in sequential order already. However, Index/Match would be less resource intensive since it's only looking up 2 columns of data, instead of 14.

Comment: @Scott: for this case INDEX/MATCH is no faster than VLOOKUP, they are both only looking up one column: what makes you think its less resource intensive?

Comment: @CharlesWilliams - the vlookup is looking across 14 columns to return the data while Index / Match is only looking at 2 columns. Albeit it may be a marginal difference at this point in Excel's evolution ([Index / Match vs Vlookup](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup/))

Comment: @Scott: That reference is not correct and does not understand how Excel functions work. VLOOKUP has not been less efficient than INDEX/MATCH in the straightforward single-use case for at least the last 13 years and probably earlier (I never tested with Excel version 4). But of course there are a lot of other advantages to INDEX/MATCH.

Answer (score 2):

While `VLOOKUP` has its uses I would always recommend using the `INDEX` function instead as you are not limited by using the leftmost column.

I think the type of formula you are looking for is (to be put in column N of spreadsheet A):

```
=INDEX('[Spreadsheet B]Sheet1'!P:P,MATCH(B1,'[Spreadsheet B]Sheet1'!C:C,0))
```

This would match the specific cell of B1 in Spreadsheet A with a value in column C in Spreadsheet B and then give provide the value in column P of the corresponding row. Obviously you should change out 'Spreadsheet B' with the name of your workbook and 'Sheet1' for the name of the worksheet in Spreadsheet B.

Comment: I agree that knowing how to use the more-versatile (and faster) [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pairs is the better way to go but it should be pointed out that there is no restriction to using the *'leftmost'* column in a [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65); only that the *col_index_num* be within the range specified by the *table_array*.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the lookup_value must be in the leftmost (or first) column of the table_array, not the leftmost in the worksheet. Thanks for clarifying.